# How do I get the print leaderboard functionality to print Name: Score?

Tags: python

I have currently a Python program that can print out a leaderboard of the top three names. What I am currently aiming to achieve is to get the `print_leaderboard` function to print the leaderboard as `Name: Score` i.e. `Bob: 12103`, instead of what is currently happening. How can I achieve this?

This is my current code:

```
# Task 1

class ScoreEntry:
    def __init__(self,name,score):
        self.name = name
        self.score = score

    def get_score(self):
        return self.score

class Scoreboard:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.scoreboard = []

    def add_score(self,name,score):
        new_entry = (score, name)
        self.scoreboard.append(new_entry)
    
    def print_leaderboard(self):
        self.scoreboard.sort(reverse=True)
        #print(self.scoreboard[0:3])
        print(self.scoreboard[0])
        print(self.scoreboard[1])
        print(self.scoreboard[2])
        
scoreboard = Scoreboard ()
scoreboard.add_score('Alice', 7821)
scoreboard.add_score('Bob', 12103)
scoreboard.add_score('Charlie', 8762)
scoreboard.add_score('Denise', 6753)
scoreboard.print_leaderboard()
```

It isn't printing exactly what I want, because I don't know how to split the name and score so I can print it as `Name: Score`, rather than `(score, 'name')` like it currently is.

Comment: You can use `self.scoreboard[0][0]` to get the score of the first player and `self.scoreboard[0][1]` to get their name. Then you can trivially combine these and format them in whatever way you prefer

Comment: Hi Mousetail,
Thank you for that. It was actually very informative and helpful and helped me a form a decent solution to my problem. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `f-strings` [Documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) to format the values in your tuples into readable strings.

```
def print_leaderboard(self):
    self.scoreboard.sort(reverse=True)
    #print(self.scoreboard[0:3])
    print(f'{self.scoreboard[0][1]}: {self.scoreboard[0][0]}')
    print(f'{self.scoreboard[1][1]}: {self.scoreboard[1][0]}')
    print(f'{self.scoreboard[2][1]}: {self.scoreboard[2][0]}')
```

You can clean the code up a little by looping over your top 3 entries after your sort, instead of writing `print` 3 times. It will also make the code much easier to read without relying on the index calls in your example.

```
def print_leaderboard(self):
    self.scoreboard.sort(reverse=True)

    for score, name in self.scoreboard[:3]:
        print(f'{name}: {score}')
```

Comment: Hi PacketLoss,
Thank you so much for both of these suggestions, they both work and are both very helpful in understanding how this can run both in a loop and out of a loop. Of course, in a loop looks much more tidy. :D

Answer (score 0):

You've defined a ScoreEntry class but are not using it when you probably should.

Override __str__ in each class.
Override __lt__ in the ScoreEntry class so that you can sort on the score

Then:

```
class ScoreEntry:
    def __init__(self, name: str, score: int) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.score = score
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.name}: {self.score}'
    def __lt__(self, other) -> bool:
        return self.score < other.score

class ScoreBoard:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.entries: list[ScoreEntry] = []
    def addScore(self, entry: ScoreEntry) -> None:
        self.entries.append(entry)
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return '\n'.join(str(entry) for entry in sorted(self.entries, reverse=True))

scoreBoard = ScoreBoard()
scoreBoard.addScore(ScoreEntry('Alice', 7821))
scoreBoard.addScore(ScoreEntry('Bob', 12103))
scoreBoard.addScore(ScoreEntry('Charlie', 8762))
scoreBoard.addScore(ScoreEntry('Denise', 6753))

print(scoreBoard)
```

**Output:**

```
Bob: 12103
Charlie: 8762
Alice: 7821
Denise: 6753
```

Comment: Hi DarkKnight,
Thank you so much for this answer, it is a great response. Works perfectly and addresses everything I need. Thank you for your suggestion to use the ScoreEntry class, as you are right, I haven't utilised it.